# Show/Hide divs using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having issues showing one div then hiding the previous div.

```
var newElem = '#ID' + numVariable;
 $('.elemPropGlobal').hide();

 $(newElem).click(function (){
   $('.elemPropGlobal').hide();

   $($(this).attr('id') + 'Properties').show();

}
```

Divs that I click on

```
<div class="something" id="ID1"  > some data</div>
<div class="something" id="ID2"  > some data</div>
```

Divs that should show and hide

```
<div class="elemPropGlobal" id="ID1Properties"  > 

<div class="elemPropGlobal" id="ID2Properties"  >
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `#`.

```
$('#' + this.id + 'Properties').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're looking for elements that are *named* `ID1Properties` etc. You need a `#` prefix to search by id!

```
$("#" + $(this).attr('id') + 'Properties').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is an oversimplification, but you're not setting the click event for both divs and  you're forgetting the hash in the second selector:

```
$(newElem).click(function (){}); //newElem is #ID1 or #ID2
```

you could do

```
    $(".something").click(function (){
       $('.elemPropGlobal').hide();

      $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + 'Properties').show();  //Remember the hash!
    });
```

Comment: I am trying to boil down 300 lines of code into an example. I have the # in there and should have added to the example. The click events are both there by the numVariable (var newElem = '#ID' + numVariable;
). I was trying to find and elegant way to show hide and wanted to make sure the code I used is best practice.

Comment: I thought so, it was just in case. Check the missing hash though :)